# How to get data from intent

Tags: android, android-service, android-notification

Не получается получить `Bandle` из `Notification`

```
public class NotificationsService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("notification", notificationModel);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOPIntent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(map.get("alert"))
                .setContentText(map.get("alert"))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_icon)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .setSound(sound);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0,notification);
    }
```

И `MainActivity` на который мы переходит по `PendingIntent`

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        notificationModel = (NotificationModel) intent.getSerializableExtra("notification");
        if (notificationModel != null){
            App.showLog(notificationModel.toString());
        }
    }
```

И в `notificationModel` приходит `null`

Answer (score 0):

```
    intent.putExtra("notification", notificationModel);
```

Чо такое notificationModel? Тут у нас точно не нулл?

```
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Зачем?

```
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOPIntent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Чоо???

Comment: Точно не null, флаги позволяют открывать уже созданные activity ну а категории(не обязательный параметр и возможно лишний) в данном случае позволяют открыть launch_activty

Comment: В уже созданном activity надо ловить `onNewIntent` - новый интент приходит только туда и автоматически не сохраняется, но Вы можете сохранить оттуда сами вызвав `setIntent`.

Comment: Всё верно, помогло

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/195154)

Comment: @kizoso Зато является отличным пинком, который помог найти ответ на вопрос.